# Error displaying webview in my android app

Tags: android, webview

I need to display a Webview in my android app. The problem is that the webpage I am trying to show gives an error:

```
"This page contains the following errors:

error on line xxx at column xxx: Entity 'abc' is not defined

Below is the rendering of the page upto the first error"
```

The site works fine on my mobile browser and also on my desktop. Also, I do not get this error with other websites

Is there anyway I can avoid this error. Kindly help.

This is the java code:

```
public class Zero extends Activity {

    WebView wv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.zero);



        wv=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);
        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        //wv.loadUrl("http://customercare.indianrailways.gov.in/criscm/common/complaint_registration.seam");
        wv.loadUrl("http://ndtv.com");
        wv.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());

        final Activity activity = this;

        wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){

             public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                     activity.setTitle("Loading...");
                     activity.setProgress(progress * 100);
                        if(progress == 100)
                           activity.setTitle("Easy Complaint Indian Railways");
                     }
    });

    }

    private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && wv.canGoBack()) {
            wv.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

The layout xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/web">
</WebView>
```

Comment: Why have you defined 2 clients and why are you setting these 2?

Comment: I was following the tutorial http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html. To be honest, I did not understand some portion of the tutorial but I have used it anyway. Please let me know if there is anything wrong in my code.. viz. using 2 clients or anything else

Comment: no..the issue is still not solved.. Please let me know if you can help in anyway.thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below activity to load your url :::

```
public class WebViewsScreenActivity extends Activity {

 private WebView mwebview;
 private WebViewsScreenActivity _activity;
 ProgressDialog _dilog;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
  getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);  
  setContentView(R.layout.webview);
  _activity = this;  
  mwebview=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
                mwebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                mwebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);

   if(checkInternetConnection(_activity)){
    if(savedInstanceState==null)    
                             mwebview.loadUrl(webUrl);
    else
     mwebview.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
   }
   else{
   //showAlert  "Unable to Connect Server"
   }
         mwebview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

            @Override
   public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
             if(mwebview.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE)
             {
             WebViewsScreenActivity  .this.setProgress(progress * 100);

             }
            }
          });
        mwebview.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
 }

@Override
 public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
  {
   mwebview.goBack();
   return true;
  }
  else
   return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
 }


//To check whether network connection is available on device or not
 private boolean checkInternetConnection(Activity _activity) {
  ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) _activity.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
  if (conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
    && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
    && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected())
   return true;
  else
   return false;
 }//checkInternetConnection()



    //HelloWebViewClient class for webview
    private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

  @Override
     public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
     }
     @Override
     public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
       String description, String failingUrl) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);

     }
     @Override
     public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      super.onPageFinished(view, url);
     }
 } //HelloWebViewClient-class
}//AccountsScreenActivity-class
```

Note::  Dont forget to add the required permission in your manifeast file.

Comment: I tried your code but am still getting the same error. I think there is something wrong with the website. But surprisingly this error does not come up when i use a browser to open the site. Anyway, thanks and please let me know if you can suggest anything else.

Comment: This is the url: http://customercare.indianrailways.gov.in/criscm/common/complaint_registration.seam